# Insert Row and sum certain cell value using Loop on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really new to VBA Excel and supervisor had me to do some macro, the ultimate purpose is inserting row and sum certain value of cells,

[please click this for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl76S.png)
I don't know what is the function but I know the logic,
Read the value of A8:B8 then read to below cell A9:B9 and so on if empty continue until the value is different then insert rows

also when Inserting rows below column "20DRY", "40DRY", "40HDRY" is SUM of cell value BAS, ERS, LSS.

Any help very appreciated.

Edit:

My question, how we add value to temporary array, and go to next cell below eg A8 go to A9, looping continuously if we found different value from current array and next array then we create a new entire row, SUM certain column?

Sorry if I didn't mention this before.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: @CodyG.just add the question, sorry was in rush before.

Comment: As your question doesn't show any code that you have attempted, most people won't respond to the question as is. You say you're 'really new' to VBA --- I particularly like  [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx) or [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/777/getting-started-with-excel-vba#t=201612091431447150221)

Comment: @CodyG.sorry just replied been busy take care other things, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you need some kind of dynamic summing methodology. If so, try the script below.

```
  totalAtoZ = 0
    For i = 7 To LastRowCusip - 1
        totalAtoZ = totalAtoZ + WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("J" & i & ":J" & i))
    Next
    
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & totalAtoZ & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```

This will start summing in row 7 and go to the end of the range, so it could go down 10 rows, or 100 rows, or more, or less.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, yes it was somekind dynamic summing, I will try this and come back as soon as possible.